# Adding background image in MaterialViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm using a library MaterialViewPager from github (https://github.com/florent37/MaterialViewPager) for my project. Instructions are given on the github page of library, but those aren't sufficient. I want to change the background of view pager header in library, programmatically. If anyone has used this library , please help. Here I'm attaching the screenshots (both from git and my project)[image: This one is from my project]
[image: This one is from git]

Answer (score 2):

in your materialViewAdapter, you should implement this function!
this part do the magic!

```
    @Override
        public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, object);

            //only if position changed
            if (position == oldPosition)
                return;
            oldPosition = position;

            int color = 0;
            String imageUrl = "";
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    imageUrl = "http://cdn1.tnwcdn.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2014/06/wallpaper_51.jpg";
                    color = getResources().getColor(R.color.blue);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    imageUrl = "https://fs01.androidpit.info/a/63/0e/android-l-wallpapers-630ea6-h900.jpg";
                    color = getResources().getColor(R.color.green);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    imageUrl = "http://www.droid-life.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/lollipop-wallpapers10.jpg";
                    color = getResources().getColor(R.color.cyan);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    imageUrl = "http://www.tothemobile.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/original.jpg";
                    color = getResources().getColor(R.color.red);
                    break;
            }

            final int fadeDuration = 400;
            mViewPager.setImageUrl(imageUrl, fadeDuration);
            mViewPager.setColor(color, fadeDuration);
            mViewPager.resetOffset(position);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in the new version you should use

```
mViewPager.setMaterialViewPagerListener(new MaterialViewPager.MaterialViewPagerListener() {
            @Override
            public HeaderDesign getHeaderDesign(int page) {
                switch (page) {
                    case 0:
                        return HeaderDesign.fromColorResAndUrl(
                                R.color.blue,
                                "http://cdn1.tnwcdn.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2014/06/wallpaper_51.jpg");
                    case 1:
                        return HeaderDesign.fromColorResAndUrl(
                                R.color.green,
                                "https://fs01.androidpit.info/a/63/0e/android-l-wallpapers-630ea6-h900.jpg");
                    case 2:
                        return HeaderDesign.fromColorResAndUrl(
                                R.color.cyan,
                                "http://www.droid-life.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/lollipop-wallpapers10.jpg");
                    case 3:
                        return HeaderDesign.fromColorResAndUrl(
                                R.color.red,
                                "http://www.tothemobile.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/original.jpg");
                }

                //execute others actions if needed (ex : modify your header logo)

                return null;
            }
        });
```